# Disable rc.local execution on boot

Tags: kernel, fedora, boot

I made some changes to rc.local on FC15 system to be executed at start. But these 
changes are now preventing fedora boot. How can I disable the execution of rc.local at boot, or revert back the changes somehow?

Comment: Are you able to boot to run-level 1?  Maybe it won't be run at that level.  Alternatively, try using a bootable CD or thumb drive, and fixing it from there.